# Is my Lenovo Thinkpad T495 too new for Debian?

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, thinkpad

I was using Ubuntu for a while with my Lenovo Thinkpad T495 which was released in May 2019.

I want to switch to Debian. I first installed it and have had lots of problems. Nothing seemed to work; my Xorg didn't even start. I did not have any home directory. After this I tried the live Debian XFCE image to check if I was doing something wrong but Debian couldn't even start.

I cannot give you some log files or errors because I directly switched back to Ubuntu. I also don't want to troubleshoot these problems.

I am just asking if my Notebook is too new for such a distro like Debian.

I have researched and see that the Debian is using kernel 4.9. 
Ubuntu runs perfectly with 5.0. Is this a reason?

Should I try to use the testing version of Debian? Or shall I just use the kernel 5.0?

Thanks in advance for some opinions to this topic.

Comment: Show us some logs of the errors, otherwise we can't guess what your problem is.

Comment: Which iso image are you using? [Try with the non free firmware images](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/)

Comment: I know but I do not have some logs. I just wanted to ask if this can be a problem in general. I directly switched back.... I was using the netinstall iso

Answer (score 1):

Debian Testing (bullseye) with Gnome Desktop Environment is working for me. Not from the beginning, though: First reboot after installation issued a blinking cursor on a black screen. I had to change to another VT <kbd>Strg+Alt+F2</kbd>, log in as root, and add `contrib non-free` to the `/etc/apt/sources.list` entries. After `apt-get update`, I could install `firmware-linux-nonfree`, `firmware-realtek`, `firmware-iwlwifi`. After the next reboot, all was fine.

Comment: I tried this solutoin but it didn't make it unfortunately. I also tried the non-free ISO but I didn't work. So I switched to Ubuntu (it's job's laptop I have not much time to spend on this).

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is based on debian...
Debian does not have contrib non-free in /etc/apt/source.conf

Try to add non-free contrib
And then update && upgrade

If you dont have a home directory reinstall debian, theres something wrong with your install